# Why is IntelliJ switching to one specific class anytime I try to run or debug anything?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am working on a project in IntelliJ where I need to make three methods in a class called Lab7, and then test all three in a separate class called Lab7Test. The code for Lab7 is from me, but the test class was given to us from our professor because we havent learned about junit and that seems to be how the tests are being run. Here is Lab7:

```
package Lab7;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // variable declarations for part 1
        String title;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // prompt for input for part 1
        System.out.print("Enter a title:");
        title = in.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
        firstName = in.next();
        System.out.print("Enter a your last name:");
        lastName = in.next();

        // call the method for part 1
        greeting(title, firstName, lastName);

        // variable declarations for part 2
        int number1;
        int number2;

        // user prompts for part 2
        System.out.print("Enter first number:");
        number1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:");
        number2 = in.nextInt();

        // call the methods max and sumTo inside the println statement
        System.out.println("The largest number is " + max(number1, number2));
        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is " + sumTo(number1, number2));
    }
    /******************** greeting method goes here*********************/
    public static void greeting(String title, String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Dear " + title + " " + firstName + " " + lastName + ",");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    /***********************end of method*************************/

    /******************** max method goes here*********************/
    public static int max(int num1, int num2){
        if(num1 >= num2){
            return num1;
        }
        else{
            return num2;
        }
    }
    /***********************end of method*************************/

    /******************** sumTo method goes here*********************/
    public static int sumTo(int num1, int num2) {
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        if(num1 == num2){
            sum = num1;
        }
        else if (num1 > num2) {
            counter = num2;
            while(counter != num1 + 1){
                sum = sum + counter;
                counter++;
            }

        }
        else if (num1 < num2){
            counter = num1;
            while(counter != num2 + 1){
                sum = sum + counter;
                counter++;
            }

        }
        return sum;
    }
    /***********************end of method*************************/
}
```

And heres Lab7Test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class Lab7Test {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    }

    @Test
    public void greetingTest() {
        Lab7.greeting("Mr.", "Buzz", "Lightyear");
        String rawOutput = outContent.toString();
        String[] outputLines = rawOutput.split("\n");
        assertEquals("", outputLines[0]);
        assertEquals("Dear Mr. Buzz Lightyear,", outputLines[1]);
    }

    @Test
    public void max10and2Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(10, 2);
        assertEquals(10, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void max2and10Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(2, 10);
        assertEquals(10, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void max50and50Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(50, 50);
        assertEquals(50, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void maxMinus10andMinus2Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(-10, -2);
        assertEquals(-2, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void maxMinus2andMinus10Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(-2, -10);
        assertEquals(-2, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void max0and0Test() {
        int max = Lab7.max(0, 0);
        assertEquals(0, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumTo2and10Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(2, 10);
        assertEquals(54, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumTo10and2Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(10, 2);
        assertEquals(54, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumTo50and50Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(50, 50);
        assertEquals(50, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumToMinus10andMinus2Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(-10, -2);
        assertEquals(-54, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumToMinus2andMinus10Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(-2, -10);
        assertEquals(-54, max);
    }

    @Test
    public void sumTo0and0Test() {
        int max = Lab7.sumTo(0, 0);
        assertEquals(0, max);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(null);
        System.setErr(null);
    }
}
```

Now, I should mention that I have to do the same thing with a different program(test the methods from one class in a different class) and it went really smoothly. The programs are called DebugLab and DebugLabTest, and I didn't have any trouble getting DebugLabTest to run the methods provided. When it comes to Lab7Test, however, the class does not recognize "Lab7" in any usage of "Lab7.(method)" and provides a cannot find symbol error code. not only does it not recognize Lab7 (which is in the same package), but any time I try to run any of the other three programs I've listed IntelliJ will jump straight back to Lab7Test and print the error codes. I have tried running the other programs from the run tab at the top, from the lightbulbs that appear beside class names, and from the buttons for running and debugging in the upper right. All of these yield the same result, the only way I have been able to run them is by deleting Lab7Test.

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Comment: I guess you need to add the package statement 'package Lab7;' to the Test class

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, class `Lab7Test` does not compile because it cannot file class `Lab7`.

If there is at least one compilation error, the whole project compilation will fail. This is how it works in a Java world, and intelliJ also works like this.

Since Tests are executed *after* the compilation (after all tests is driven by a regular java process, read, JVM spawned for this purposes) that obviously works with binary code, so you have compile the stuff first.

Now, say you have a complication error in `Lab7Test`. Since the compilation fails, this means that you won't be able to run any test in that module including `DebugLabTest` of course.
When you deleted the `Lab7Test` the error gone so you can proceed.

So far so good, now in terms of resolution.

You should always check what exactly the compilation errors are. The java compiler is really a "clever" piece of software and it can help you to resolve the error.

You haven't posted the actual compile error in `Lab7Test` class, but I guess it fails to file `Lab7`

If so, you should make sure that they reside in the same package. Because if they don't, `Lab7Test` must contain a line with an "explicit" import of `Lab7`. It looks like it doesn't, and the class `Lab7Test` resides in a default package (the is no line like `package abc;` in the File `Lab7Test`. So make sure that Lab7 also resides in the same (default) package, or alternatively add the line `import foo.bar.Lab7;` to `Lab7Test.java` assuming you really want `Lab7` file to reside in the package `foo.bar`

P.S. this answer might probably look too scrupulous but obviously its asked by a person who does his/her first steps in programming, so it was by intention :)